# Angular 6: How to unsubscribe rsjx interval or timer?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I think the question is clear. I coudn't find any informations about how to unsubscribe from a `rsjx`-operation like `interval or timer`?

My Component:

```
public intervallTimer = interval(5000);

ngOnInit() {
  this.getValues();
  this.intervallTimer.subscribe(() => this.getValues());
}

// What I like to do is something like this, but "unsubscribe()" that's no function
somefunction(){
  this.intervallTimer.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: You need to `unsubscribe` the `Subscription` you get from calling `.subscribe()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`subscribe` returns a `Subscription` object that has `unsubscribe` as a method. One option that you have is:

```
public intervallTimer = interval(5000);
private subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getValues();
  this.subscription = this.intervallTimer.subscribe(() => this.getValues());
}

somefunction(){
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

This requires you to explicitly unsubscribe from subscriptions, which you may not want to do. You could also consider using `takeUntil`, which returns a `complete` `Observable` that will cause an automatic `unsubscribe`. Just make sure that `takeUntil` is [the last in any chain](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef).

```
public intervallTimer = interval(5000);
private alive = true;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getValues();
  this.intervallTimer.pipe(takeUntil(() => !this.alive)).subscribe(() => this.getValues());
}

somefunction(){
  this.alive = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `takeWhile(Boolean)` to control the behaviour

```
this.intervallTimer.pipe(
      takeWhile(// your condition)
).subscribe(() => this.getValues());
```

you can find the documentation from [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeWhile)